# Magento installing error

Tags: magento

I tried to install magento in my PC. but it occurred error like this.

I used localhost to install this.it is wampserver 2.1 version.

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception Object
(
    [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'period'
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42000
    [file:protected] => C:\wamp\www\Magento\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php
    [line:protected] => 234
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\Magento\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php
                    [line] => 110
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\Magento\magento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php
                    [line] => 291
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )..................
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: As it stands this isn't really a programming question. Try asking on Magento

Comment: Which magento version are u installing?

Comment: 1.8.1.0 @DushyantJoshi

Comment: did you try http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/2012/03/03/syntax-error-or-access-violation-1067-invalid-default-value-for-period/ ?

Answer (score 0):

alter your magento database as following :

> ALTER TABLE `coupon_aggregated` CHANGE `period` `period` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' COMMENT 'Period'

basicaly you have to set a default value (0000-00-00) for the period field in the coupon_aggregated table